# How to add external JS script to product page in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I'm trying to add a JS Script for some specific products in the product detail page but I dont know how to.
I know I can edit the xml file and add scripts there... but the source of the script specified doing it that way.

```
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/src/externalScript.js</name>
            </action>
```

The script I'm trying to add has a external source so Im a bit confused on how to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some_external_source"></script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look how other modules are adding they CSS/JS to Magento. In this example I am going to use a snippet from the Adyen Extension:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>adyenstyle.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>adyencheckout.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>adyen/payment/iban.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>adyen/adminhtml/sales.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

This is taken from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout`. In this example you can see that the Magento XML can be called by a reference, in this example its `adminhtml_sales_order_create_index`, which matches the Layout Name of the given view.

You can see that the child node referenced by `head` accepts `action` xml nodes that can have a method parameter (in our case `addCss` and `addJs`), that accept more xml nodes to specify what to add exactly. For CSS files the parameter name is `stylesheet` and for JS scripts, its `script`.

Now, to add a JS to any given product page in Magento, you can add something like this to your `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/page.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view>
      <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>path/to/your.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>path/to/your.js</script>
            </action>
      </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Don't forget to clear your cache after you are making any changes to XML files in Magento, as they are often being cached, unless you deactivate the respective Cache for XMLs in the Backend.